# Dragon NaturallySpeaking's accuracy improvement over versions

Tags: computers, software, voice

Dragon NaturallySpeaking's editor Nuance [claims](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-product/dragon/dragon-for-the-pc/dragon-professional/index.htm) that Dragon 12 delivers up to a 20% improvement in out-of-box accuracy compared to Dragon 11. Nuance made similar claims in the past with previous versions. Are there any rigorous studies to verify this commercial claim?

Comment: I tend to that there will be peer-reviewed studies of the efficacy of the commercial product, especially one that is in constant development. Anecdotally, I can say that the quality of dictation has improved between Dragon generations, but the software still makes frequent errors, some of which are easy to fix, others, not so much.  <- This comment transcribed by Dragon dictate without correction.

Comment: [This informal test](http://blog.classroomteacher.ca/750/how-accurate-is-dragon-naturallyspeaking-11-using-the-rainbow-passage-to-measure-accuracy/) found, at its worst, Dragon 11 was 87.6% accurate out-of-the-box.. What does it mean to offer a 20% improvement on that?

Comment: @Oddthinking Some people mean a 20% reduction in error rate, which in this case, would be reducing an error rate of 12.4% to 9.9%.

Comment: @Articuno exactly, use whichever number that looks larger and more impressive for marketing; no-one checks them anyway ;)

Comment: @Oddthinking I don’t think that’s a meaningful number. 87% accuracy is abysmal and altogether useless for practical application. You need accuracy upwards of 98% (or thereabouts) for it to be a useful product. So the out-of-the-box accuracy doesn’t seem to be an informative number.